# Clamp to Constraint Offsetting Bone in Pose Mode, but Snap to Cursor isn't Working

Tags: bones

Recently I have posted a few questions trying to extract an answer, but since I have not. I added a clamp to constraint and linked it with a belzier circle, but it offset the bone in pose mode. I need to know how to snap the bone to the cursor in pose mode. It is not working.

Here is a picture!

[image]

I want the blue bone to be on the cursor. Any ideas on how to make it not offset? Keep in mind I extruded that bone directly on a belzier joint, so there should be no reason clamping it moves it, since it's already directly on the belzier. Please help I'm lost :(